# How do you read a resource from the root of an exploded webapp?

Tags: web-applications, resources, jboss, classpath, exploded

I have a localhost JBoss 6 setup with JBoss Tools and Eclipse doing the hot deploy of an **exploded** webapp. I used to launch my webapp via shell using main class with an explicit classpath and via JAR/WAR file. My resource loader used to work perfectly, but now since the webapp is on JBoss in an exploded directory structure with an "unknown" classpath, text file resources like "/db/jpql/whatever.jpql" aren't found (null is returned, leading to an NPE).

The question is:

How do you load resources from the root (or outside of the WEB-INF dir) of an exploded webapp (in JBoss)? I checked the classpath which is nothing but C:\dev\jboss\bin\run.jar...

Comment: It should work as before, if you were using the "correct" approach. Show us the code you use to load the resource.

Comment: You were right. Coding error.

Comment: You should post that as an answer and mark it as accepted, then. Otherwise, delete the question.

Comment: That's up to you. Like I said, either post your solution as an answer for other people to find, or just delete the whole thing yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had "forgotten" to prefix my resource strings with a slash. Can't work reliably.

I had used

```
public static String readResource(String sResource)
{
    String sContent = "";

    InputStream is = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;

    try
    {
        is = TextFileLoader.class.getResourceAsStream(sResource);

        // resource not found, check web environment
        if ( is == null )
        {
            is = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream(sResource);
        }

        is.available();

        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

to get the webapp resource if the current classes' classloader returned null.